# Android Studio "Run" not timeout only for pixel/nexus devices

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I've been testing my app on several AVDs and only recently (after attempting to integrate Google's billing system), the "Run" window only shows the following:

11/24 16:31:18: Launching 'xxx' on Nexus 5X API 27.
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
$ adb shell am start -n "xxxx.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Timed out waiting for process (xxx) to appear on Nexus_5X_API_27 [emulator-5554].

I've tested on Pixel 4, Pixel 3a and Nexus 5X (all these are with Play Store in them) and they all timed out. If i run the same app on other AVDs without Play Store, the Run window works fine.

Any idea how to fix this? I'm trying to troubleshoot the billing process for my app.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was setting the Graphics option on the Android Virtual Device to Software instead of Automatic or Hardware.

I believe this was the solution because I am working on a windows machine that did not have a dedicated graphics card.

Note : Clone your device before adding it. Then you'll be able to edit it.

Comment: after cloning the device, it loses the playstore.